# How to work with XML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, json

So in Javascript I'm working with json a lot.

It's simple since it looks like js object. So all I need to do when getting a json back from a HTTP request is to parse it to js object. When I want to send a js object as json i stringify it.

But some APIs are just returning XML.

How do I interact with XML? I parse it to object with a XMLtoObject lib? Is there a built in method in js?

Or do I use xpath/css selector to get what I want in that string? How do I add elements etc.

Hope someone could shed a light on this topic.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/), a crossbrowser library that encapsulate the XML APIs. It has XPATH, XSLT transformation and it is quite simple to use.

It supports almost all modern browser and different old ones, refer to the sites for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just stay away from W3C DOM HTML stuff, other than that it works just like an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You parse XML with an XML parser. All modern browsers have one built in, but working with it is not exactly trivial, nor cross-platform. See [ww3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp) for a short tutorial, to get you started.

Comment: See [this](http://w3fools.com/) instead.